# Estoy trabajando con la libreria de jest para hacer un mock de kafka de un callback y pasar un test de conexión ok pero me da error

Tags: javascript, callback, jestjs

Este mock uso la libreria de node-rdkafka, y tengo el siguiente mock:

```
const getMetadataFn = jest.fn();

const kafkaClientRdMock =  {
  client: {
    getMetadata: () => ({ getMetadata: getMetadataFn })
  }, 
  libray: 'node-rdkafka',
  topics: [ 'test5' ],
  status: 200   
};
```

Este es el fichero de kafka donde tengo la configuración de la conexión:

```
const getKafkaRdMetadata = ({ client, topics = [] }) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      client.getMetadata({}, function(err, metadata) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }

        const metadataTopics = B(
          pluck('name'),
          propOr([])('topics')
        )(metadata);

        const invalidTopics = filter(notIncluded(metadataTopics))(topics);

        if (notEmpty(invalidTopics)) {
          return reject(new Error(`Error on kafka connection, invalid topics: ${invalidTopics}`));
        }

        resolve({
          timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
          topics,
          status: 200
        })
      });
    }
)
```

Y por último este es el test que estoy lanzando:

```
    it('Should return healthcheck Ok if ping is successfull', async () => {

      getMetadataFn.mockResolvedValueOnce({ topics: kafkaClientRdMock.topics });
   
      const results = await checkConnections({
        kafka: kafkaClientRdMock
      });

      expect(Array.isArray(results)).toBe(true);
      expect(results).toHaveLength(1);
      forEach((result) => {
        expect(result).toHaveProperty('type', 'node-rdkafka');
        expect(result).toHaveProperty('topics', (kafkaClientRdMock.topics));
        expect(result).toHaveProperty('status', 200);
        expect(result).toHaveProperty('timestamp');
      })(results)

      expect(getMetadataFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
  
});
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)

```
Expected length: 1
Received length: 0
Received array:  []
expect(Array.isArray(results)).toBe(true);
> 200 |       expect(results).toHaveLength(1);
      |                       ^
```

Comment: Estoy haciendo el test con done ya que al usar un callback debe usarse done en vez de async/await pero tampoco consigo mucho avance :(

Comment: Me he permitido ordenar un poco el código, usando un estilo algo más estándar para mejorar la legibilidad. Creo que hay un par de erratas: libray en lugar de library y una llamada a forEach sin `results.` delante.

Comment: Gracias Pablo! bien visto!!!